# Instagram API only working in the browser

Tags: javascript, fetch, instagram-api

I'm trying to get the instagram userId of a user from it's username. For that, I use the following endpoint of Instagram's API `https://www.instagram.com/<username>/?__a=1`.

Accessing that endpoint in the browser yield some JSON `application/json` with the infos I need.

ex. https://www.instagram.com/deletethistheo/?__a=1

Now if I go over the network tab and copy that request as fetch()

```js
const res = await fetch("https://www.instagram.com/deletethistheo/?__a=1", {
  "headers": {
    "accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9",
    "accept-language": "en-US,en;q=0.9,fr-FR;q=0.8,fr;q=0.7",
    "cache-control": "max-age=0",
    "sec-ch-ua": "\" Not A;Brand\";v=\"99\", \"Chromium\";v=\"90\", \"Google Chrome\";v=\"90\"",
    "sec-ch-ua-mobile": "?0",
    "sec-fetch-dest": "document",
    "sec-fetch-mode": "navigate",
    "sec-fetch-site": "cross-site",
    "sec-fetch-user": "?1",
    "upgrade-insecure-requests": "1"
  },
  "referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
  "body": null,
  "method": "GET",
  "mode": "cors",
  "credentials": "omit"
});

console.log(await res.json());
```

and run that in the chrome console or in a node.js program. I get a HTML response of a blank page.

I also tried setting the `user-agent` header to mine: `user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36` but  got the same result.

EDIT: Something weird too, sometimes when I copy as fetch and run the fetch in the chrome console, I get the expected JSON result. And when I re run that same code few minutes after, I get an error.

[image]

I don't understand what can be causing that difference of behaviour given the request made is the same. Any ideas?

Cheers!

Comment: In the console it flat-out says it's a CORS error; perhaps that's why.

Comment: @DaveNewton I also tried changing the http referer to the same origin "www.instagram.com" same issue :/

Comment: *You* do not get to control the *server's* CORS policies--that would render CORS pointless.

Comment: @DaveNewton but CORS on the server act on the referer header. If I spoof that, the server should have no way of knowing where my request comes from right?

Answer (score 0):

From their API docs it sounds like you'll need to append any requests with an access token:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-profiles-and-media

Specifically this section of the docs:

---

Step 2: Query the User node
Send a request to the following endpoint:

```
GET /me?fields={fields}&access_token={access-token}
```

Replace {fields} with a comma-separated list of User fields you want returned and {access-token} with the user’s access token. The GET /me endpoint will determine the user’s ID from the token and redirect the request to the User node.

Sample Request

```
curl -X GET \
  'https://graph.instagram.com/me?fields=id,username&access_token=IGQVJ...'
Sample Response
{
  "id": "17841405793187218",
  "username": "jayposiris"
}
```